# Update form redirection URL depending on radio button value with JS

Tags: javascript, forms, url, radio-button

I try to update a form redirection URL depending on the value of the selected radio button of the form.

For instance,

If button value = 1, then go to mywebsite.com/page-a

or

If button value = 2, then go to mywebsite.com/page-b

You'll find here the code I've done so far (jsfiddle below) :

```
<label class="labl">
<input type="radio" name="quantite" value="1" checked="checked"/>
<div>
<span class="box"><b>First choice</b></span><br>
</div>
</label>
<label class="labl">
<input type="radio" name="quantite" value="2" />
<div>
<span class="box"><b>Second choice</b></span><br>
</div>
</label>
<label class="labl">
<input type="radio" name="quantite" value="3" />
<div>
<span class="box"><b>Third choice</b></span><br>
</div>
</label>
```

And JS

```
$('!selector!').parents("form").attr("action","https://www.mywebsite.com");

$('!selector!').on('change', function(){
var newValue = parseInt($(this).val());
var $form = $(this).parents("form");

switch(newValue){
case 1:
$form.attr("action", "https://www.mywebsite.com/page-a/");
break;
case 2:
$form.attr("action", "https://www.mywebsite.com/page-b/");
break;
case 3:
$form.attr("action", "https://www.mywebsite.com/page-c/");
break;
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pcL8vfvn/

But nothing happen when I change the selected button and submit my form.

I think there is a flaw in the JS code.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: The shown code and JS Fiddle example are incomplete. Also both say nothing about jQuery, which - from the looks of it - is used. Why do you want it to be a form? Why not just use links?

Comment: Because I have other informations to be completed in the form and to be posted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fluent in jQuery, but this logs the correct values:

```
$('input[name="quantite"]').on('change', function()
 {
  var newValue = parseInt($(this).val());
  console.log(JSON.stringify(newValue));
 });
```

It attaches the function to the `onchange` event of each radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the easiest solution by adding this as an attribute the each radio button :

```
onclick="document.getElementById('my-form').action='https://www.mywebsite.com/page-x';"
```

It works like a charm !